# Batch Programming - Not deleting partial files being written

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I am trying to develop a batch script which copies a list of files from the a source directory to another directory and does some functions. Once the copy has been done, the files needs to be deleted from the source directory.

In the source directory, we are receiving files on real time basis 24x7 from an external source.

How can I make sure, the copy or the delete from the script does not impact any files which are currently being sent (incomplete files which are in relay at that moment) from the external source in the source directory, whilst the script is doing its own job?

The script needs to be ran every 5 minutes.

Due to some challenges, we cannot xxcopy for our functionality.

Please can you advise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `COPY`& `DELETE` use `MOVE`, so the batch fragment would look like this:

```
FOR %%F IN (C:\SOURCE\*.*) DO MOVE %%F C:\TARGET\
```

If file in incomplete (other process uses it), then `MOVE` on that file will fail. Next time the script is run, it will attempt to move that file again.

Comment: Quote in case there are space characters in the file names. `FOR %%F IN (C:\SOURCE\*.*) DO (MOVE "%%~F" C:\TARGET\)`